# Can I exchange a note of 1000 Swiss Francs in Georgia?

Tags: exchange, georgia-country

I own a single note of 1000 Swiss Francs, (CHF) pristine. And a valid EU passport. Can I walk into a bank in Georgia and exchange it for GEL? I only need it to travel as a tourist. Wondering if they exchange Swiss Francs at all, and if they would take a 1000 CHF note.

Comment: Not familiar with Georgia, but in most ex-CIS countries, it's much faster & easier to use a money exchange office than a bank, and you'll likely get better rates too.  Try to get local, unbiased advice on where to do it though, particularly for a sum that large, and check the money they give you carefully.